# Mysql - Get # of months and years

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any way to get the # of months and years since a date, using the mysql DATE column?

So if I enter 1/1/2009.. I want 1 years, 3 months.. and so on.

Comment: Well, it's 2010, that would be 1 year.  And currently March 17th, making it over 3 months.  So jwzk is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DateDiff](http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/func_datediff_mysql.asp) can return the difference in days between two dates.  <strike>From there, you might have to do the math yourself.  You could make a Stored Procedure with all the logic, but for the most part SQL isn't designed as a functional language.</strike>

**EDIT:** I found what you are looking for.  Try this:

```
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), <date>)), '%c months and %Y years')
```

Comment: It would be tough to extract the months from datediff() results, because months vary in the number of days they contain.  Years would be close if you ignored leap year.

Answer (score 0):

Within a SQL query, or with PHP?

http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/showthread.php?t=10362190

Comment: preferably SQL, if its possible

Answer (score 0):

```
select mnth as months_between, mnth/12 as years_between
from
( select (year(<current date column>) - year(<older date column>))*12 +
         (month(<current date column>) - month(<older date column)) as mnth
  from <tables with date columns>
  where <conditions to get your rows with the dates you need to compare>
)
```

Also cf. Anthony Mollinaro's [SQL Cookbook](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596009762/), chapter 8 on Date Arithmetic.

Comment: If you want to use today's date, you can substitute `NOW()` for the current date column.

Comment: Not 100% accurate as you may encounter a situation like 2009/03/15 2009/02/16.  This would not be 1 month, but the return value of your script would be.

Comment: I think it depends on OPs business requirements, whether a comparison between the two would be 1/0.  But yes, you are technically correct.